# MATLAB USB HID data receive

Tags: matlab, usb, hid

Is there a way to receive the data sent over USB to PC using HID protocol in MATLAB? I tried the host hid receiver block found in STM32 blockset in Simulink but it gives an error saying that STM32 device not found so I guess that blockset is spesific for a STM32 device.

Answer (score 0):

Under Linux, you can read from /dev/input/mice. It covers position data and clicks. You might need to adjust the reading privileges of the device file.